# SQL find student who never was at the class(no subqueries or aggregates)

Tags: sql, join

So we have two tables:
 
**students**

```
id | name
1  | st1
2  | st2
3  | st3
```

**classes**

```
id | title    | student_id | visited
1  | class1   |  1         | false
2  | class2   |  1         | true
3  | class3   |  1         | false
4  | class4   |  1         | false
5  | class5   |  2         | true
6  | class6   |  3         | false
```

And the question is *how to find students who never were at the classes **without subqueries or aggregate functions** (only joins and alias are allowed).* 
 I honestly tried to find out the solution but failed and lost the hope it even exists.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37255021/writing-a-query-with-a-not-exists-clause-without-a-subquery-for-the-not-exists

Comment: Show any parts you can do. For code questions give a [mre]. Also this is (clearly) a faq. Before considering posting please read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask], other [help] links, hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL, I would do this with a filtered outer outer join:

```
select s.*
from students s
  left join classes c on s.id = c.student_id and c.visited
where c.id is null;
```

But a NOT EXISTS condition with a sub-query is typically more efficient.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=d552082e8a75a5406a7da73d72712a8d)

Comment: wow, this is exactly what i needed! Thanx so much for spending your time helping me, the answer turned out to be so simple but somehow i didn't see it eheh c: